# Creating a WP Test site without /uploads etc

Tags: customization

I would like to create a test site for a huge wordpress live site (a news site). It has tons of images in /wp-content/uploads and /wp-content/gallery, and other folders of /wp-content are also packed with stuff, so duplicating all that takes a very very long time.

How can I setup a test site by copying the live site without the /wp-content folder but just linking to it somehow? Nothing needs to be changed or uploaded in /wp-content, just to see and read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a hard or symbolic link. However, you would of course need to take care that testing doesn't affect the contents of `wp-content`.

Another approach would be to put `wp-content` (or a copy) into its own file system partition (or just make a `.img` file from it). Then `dd` (or its Windows analog) should duplicate it fairly quickly.

As an aside, its worth asking if you really need a complete copy of the large set of files in `wp-content`. Unless you're doing performance testing, perhaps a well-chosen subset would suffice.

added:
One thing to check is whether anything important behaves differently with a symbolic link. The one case that comes to mind is recursive deletion of the test directory tree. IIRC it will detect the existence of the symlink and delete it but not recurse into it, avoiding unintentional deletion of part of the production set-up. So here the difference is actually a good thing. (But I'd double-check the correctness of this.) (This might also be a reason to do a soft (symbolic) link instead of a hard link.)

Comment: Where would I create a hard or symbolic link? I's rather not change anything in the filesystem settings...but maybe this can also be done in wp-config?

Comment: Would this be a good Idea?
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content' );

Comment: I just noticed that setting the WP_CONTENT_URL to the live site wp-content folder is a bad idea if you want to test core and plugin updates...because tha plugins are inside wp-content/plugins. So, I'll go for your other idea and copy only a few of the content files. Thank you!